# Is there a configuration tool for gitattributes?

Tags: git

Is there any GUI based tool to help configuring the .gitattributes file? that traverse the working directory to extract all the used file types; then helps me to config each type!

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.

Setting `.gitattributes` directives remains a manual process, each subfolder `.gitattributes` overriding parent folder `.gitattributes`.